# Rendering a Play Framework 2 View

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm just kind of confused as a whole when it comes to play framework. I've gotten most of everything figured out, but it seems like every day something new comes up.

Anyway, the thing of the day is this: my scala template code is showing up as plain text in my rendered document. Maybe its the wrong syntax, maybe its play 1.0 syntax, I dunno. The template looks like this:

```
@(model : models.Menu)

@main("Bearings") {

<div id="bearings_container">

    <div id="menu">
    <ul id="firstLevel">
    #{list items:model.items,as:'menuItem'}
        <li id="${menuItem.name}" class="firstLevel">${menuItem.name}</li>
        <ul id="${menuItem.name}- submenu">
        #{list items: menuItem.subMenu, as:'subMenuItem'}
            <li id="${subMenuItem.name}" class="secondLevel">${subMenuItem.name}</li>
            <ul id="${subMenuItem.name}- submenu">
            #{list items: subMenuItem.subMenu, as:'subSubMenuItem'}
            <li id="${subSubMenuItem.name}" class="thirdlevel">${subSubMenuItem.name}</li>
            #{/li}
            </ul>
        #{/li}
        </ul>
    #{/li}
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple. Any ideas?

Edit: here's the controller action:

```
public static Result bearings()
{
    Menu menu = BuildMenu();
    return ok(views.html.bearings.render(menu));
}
```

And the result is what a straight HTML result of the code above would look like.

Comment: Whole code or its parts ? Show us the action from the controller, where you are rendering this view.

Comment: I think you're using [Play 1.0 template syntax](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/templates#syntax). The template syntax in Play 2 [is completely different](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTemplates).

Comment: Nota bene as @rjsvaljean wrote of course you are mixing Play 1 and Play 2 in these parts: `#{list items...`

Comment: I have to say, that I have no idea o.O

Comment: @rjsvaljean Crap. That's like 3 questions in a row that have had like the simplest answer possible. Post what you said as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I just hope the answer isn't so simple or localized or something that it's closed. That'd be like the 3rd question I've answered that's closed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [Play 1.0 template syntax](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/templates#syntax). The template syntax in [Play 2 is completely different](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTemplates).

To be fair the play documentation does make this confusion easy. I've found myself reading a Play 1.0 documentation page that I get to from a Google search for a while before I realize that the URL says 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

If the output looks like straight HTML I'd try checking the template referred by `@main`. Please provide the `main` template source.